# Folder protection for windows7

Tags: windows-7, data-protection

sir,
      which folder lock software is suitable for windows7 home premium original version,

in my laptop i want to lock and hide some folders and data and i try some folder lock softwares and all of them create some problems in my lap performance,i list some softwares and their problems

software name:folder lock 7 Company: New Softwares.net:

this will provide folder lock and hiding capability but in some time when we unlock the data we does not get the data from the current position(the data is always their but it is invisible) 
then we have to uninstall the folder lock to access the data

software name:password folder from: IObit.com:

when using this one it will disable the os "superfetch" technology and there by reduce the speed of the os.we canot activate superfetch untill uninstall the password folder(this is only happend in laptops)

so please give the name of the software to lock the folders and files which cannot 
reduce the speed and performance of the laptops............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used my-lockbox and it provide better performance

http://fspro.net/my-lockbox/

Answer (score 0):

Most file and folder lock software, like the one you mention, naively use hard drive serial number as the key to prevent use of that file on other drives. So if you have to replace files from a backup or replace a hard drive, your precious files will be useless to you.

If you want to protect files, simply encrypt them. If you want to protect access to files in a folder, simply use Windows permissions to set user rights... for whichever you user you want, and then if you are not using the account that does have access permissions, your will be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should go for winrar its very conman software and everyone has this software in his or her pc you can make password protected folder with this software you can see this step by step youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_koso3Nryc it will help to to make password protected folder or file which will be encrypted and no one can see files in it without password.